# Problem with subfig, ref and renewcommand

Tags: floats, hyperref, subfloats

I have a problem with using the `subfigure` package and the corresponding references.

I'm wirting my thesis and I want the Figure to be named like this

```
\numberwithin{figure}{part}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{figure}}
```

This works fine.

If I now have a `subfigure` I want the Output to be  like `1.1.a` (Part,Figure,Subfigure) but i only get `1.a` (Figure,Subfigure)

I tried to use

```
\numberwithin{subfigure}{part}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{figure}.\alph{subfigure
} }
```

But this screws up the caption of the figure.
I include subfigure in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[][]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Picture1}
\label{fig:Picture1}}
\subfigure[][]{\vspace{2pt}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Picture2.png}
\label{fig:Picture2}}
 \caption[What is seen on Pic1 and 2 ]{(a)text Pic 1 (b) text Pic 2}
\end{figure}
```

And refer to it with `\ref{fig:Picutre1}`. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You do not need to add your name at the bottom, better to update your details so that the display name is not the random "user....".

Comment: Please include a MWE so we know which class you are using for example

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your redefine the figure numbering before loading the `subfigure` package.  Then you should get the output you wish.

Note that `\numberwithin` already changes the label format, so your `\renewcommand`s are redundant.  If you wish to change the printed representation of `part` in these references, then you should do this by redefining `\thepart`.  This will make the change consistent.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{part}
\usepackage{subfigure,graphicx}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\begin{document}

\part{A part}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[][]{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\label{fig:Picture1}}
\subfigure[][]{\vspace{2pt}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\label{fig:Picture2}}
 \caption[What is seen on Pic1 and 2]{(a) text Pic 1 (b) text Pic 2}
\end{figure} 

A reference to \ref{fig:Picture2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Just reordering the include commands solved the problem :) I need the renewcommand to change the style  from I.1.a to 1.1.a ;)

Comment: Glad it helps.  If you wish to change the style of the part numbering then you should do this consistently, redefining `\thepart` instead.